# sharepoint site owner: Access Denied

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, permissions

I was editing the permissions of my SharePoint site and accidentally ticked my e-mail as well to view only.

I do get requests for permissions but I get looped back to Access Denied. I am the only author and editor of SharePoint site.

How do I restore my full control?

Comment: Does anyone has the site collection administrator permissions on that site?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm the only one. I get an email to approve site permission of my own request but I get the following error: Correlation ID: 1ec4449f-9033-2000-c524-b7046b2d9675 
Date and Time: 4/2/2020 1:49:57 AM 
Issue Type: User does not have permissions.

Comment: Do you have any content in this site? like lists/libraries or it is just newly created site?

Comment: Yes there's already content

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask your SharePoint Administrator to add your account as site admins to this site.

1. Go to the Active sites page of the new SharePoint admin center and sign in with an account that has admin permissions for your organization.
2. In the left column, click to select a site.
3. Select Permissions. For a group-connected team site, you can add and remove group owners and additional site admins. For other sites, you can add and remove site admins and change the primary admin. Note that if you remove a person as a primary admin, they will still be listed as an additional admin.

Please refer to this article:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-site-collection-administrators

Comment: Unfortunately I am the sharepoint site's author and admin.. however i accidentally edited my permission to view only.

Comment: As I said, you could go to sharepoint online admin center. And add yourself as site admin there.

Comment: thank you, Michael

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helps you.